# How do Raishin's spells for commanding Yaya work?

Tags: unbreakable-machine-doll

In Unbreakable Machine Doll, Raishin has certain spells which seem to command Yaya to take certain actions. Assuming I haven't misunderstood the Japanese words, he first calls out an elemental attribute, then a number, then something like an attack style.

I think the elements he's choosing from are just the [Fuurinkazan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C5%ABrinkazan). I might guess that the number affects how strong the attack is, but they also always seem to be significant numbers in Eastern culture and tradition so it could be something different.

I don't really know what all the possible styles are or what they do. It also seems that there are certain special attacks which don't exactly fit this pattern, e.g. the finishing move Yaya uses on Eliza in episode 4.

How exactly do these spells/commands work?
To be clear, I'm looking for a more in-depth explanation of what exactly they do and what all the possible options are.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of spells:

- **Tactics** (戦術, *senjutsu*) to control Yaya's magical circuit, "Herculean Strength" (金剛力, *kongouriki*)
- **Absolute skills** (絶衝, *zesshou*) based on the tactic

---

#### Tactics

The spell is **Pattern (magical nature) + Number (magical power) + Formation**

There are 4 **patterns** which are comparable to [*Fuurinkazan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C5%ABrinkazan):

- **吹**鳴 (*suimei*, blowing [a whistle]) / whistle: increase the agility/speed, "*as swift as wind*"
- **森**閑 (*shinkan*, stillness): strengthen the defense, "*as gentle as forest*"
- 光**焔** (*kouen*, light & flame) / flare: increase the number of attacks/power, "*as fierce as fire*"
- 天**嶮** (*tenken*, natural defenses) / stronghold: increase the attack power/durability, "*as unshakable as mountain*"

(However, according to an interview on *Monthly Comic Alive 2012-9* with Reiji Kaito, the author of the series, he mentioned that *suimei* is for speed, *shinkan* is preserving magical power with things that aim for counters, *kouen* is for both speed and attack, and *tenken* is for defense)

The **number** represents the power. The higher the number, the more powerful it affects. As for now, it seems the number is always a multiple of 12 with the highest being 48.

The **formation** is separated into 2 types:

- 衝 (*shou*, thrust): Yaya attacks independently
- 結 (*ketsu*, bind): Yaya attacks first on a cooperative attack

Some examples:

- 吹鳴二四衝: 吹鳴 (*suimei*) + 二四 (*ni-jyuu-yon*, 24) + 衝 (*shou*)
- 光焔十二結: 光焔 (*kouen*) + 十二 (*jyuu-ni*, 12) + 結 (*ketsu*)

---

#### Skill

The spell is **Pattern (magical nature) + "Absolute" (絶衝, *zesshou*) + Name**

The **pattern** follows the previously mentioned pattern.

The **name** is just a proper noun.

The skills from the first 4 volumes corresponding to each pattern are:

- 天嶮絶衝<破却水月>: 天嶮 (*tenken*) + 絶衝 (*zesshou*) + 破却水月 (*hakyaku suigetsu*, destruction of the moon reflected on the water) / Final Stronghold "Razing Moon Reflection": By striking a blow against an opponent in a hardened state, Yaya can interfere with the opponent's magic and cause it to lose control.
- 吹鳴絶衝<ひさぎ太刀影【たちかげ】>: 吹鳴 (*suimei*) + 絶衝 (*zesshou*) + ひさぎ太刀影 (*hisagi tachikage*, silhouette of [Catalpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalpa_bungei) long sword): By sending several ten times of the magical power, Yaya jumps to the air in a flash, almost looks like disappearing.
- 光焔絶衝<乱れ夜桜>: 光焔 (*kouen*) + 絶衝 (*zesshou*) + 乱れ夜桜 (*midare yozakura*, disturbance of cherry trees at evening): By sending out the magical power to the whole body, Yaya does a super rush attack by punching & kicking relentlessly while in that state. Even if each attack may be light, the attack rush can be continued while maintaining the magical power.
- 森閑絶衝<神機御雷【しんきみかづち】>: 森閑 (*shinkan*) + 絶衝 (*zesshou*) + 神機御雷 (*shinki mikazuchi*, miraculous thunder): Attack the downed opponent by hitting using the fist in the manner of [tile splitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mFlEl.jpg). A single blow that has enough power to sink the opponent's body to the ground by as much as 10 meters.

However, the 8th volume introduced 光焔絶衝<月影紅蓮> (*kouen zesshou tsukikage guren*, moonlight crimson lotus flower) and thus, there's a high possibility that other skills also exist.

(by the way, the previous skill does a reddish, intense rotation kick that can cause burning due to the air friction.)

---

**Note from Nico Nico Pedia**: the original source (light novel) itself doesn't explain the detail for both the tactics and skills and thus, it can only be interpreted by the reader/viewer from the given evidence.

---

References:

- [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A9%9F%E5%B7%A7%E5%B0%91%E5%A5%B3%E3%81%AF%E5%82%B7%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84#.E4.B8.BB.E4.BA.BA.E5.85.AC)
- [Nico Nico Pedia (Japanese)](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E5%A4%9C%E3%80%85)
- [Hissatsu Waza Jiten (Japanese)](http://hissatuwaza.kill.jp/setume/masindo-ru.htm)
- [Yahoo! Chiebukuro (Japanese)](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12117027332)
- Wikia

  - [Magic Circuit](http://kikoshojowakizutsukanai.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Circuit#Types)
  - [Yaya](http://kikoshojowakizutsukanai.wikia.com/wiki/Yaya#Powers_.26_Abilities)